# Laravel 7 select from table with two columns having ids from a Single Table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

**My requirement?**

If i am the logged in user with Id = 1, then through the **Messages** Table i want to select users from **Users** Table to whom i sent the message or from whome i received the message.

**Table 1: Users**

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | email |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | a    | ???   |
|  2 | b    | ???   |
|  3 | c    | ???   |
|  4 | d    | ???   |
|  5 | e    | ???   |
|  6 | f    | ???   |
|  7 | g    | ???   |
|  8 | h    | ???   |
|  9 | i    | ???   |
| 10 | j    | ???   |
+----+------+-------+
```

**Table 2: Messages**

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | user_id | receiver_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 |           2 |
|  2 |       3 |           1 |
|  3 |       4 |           1 |
|  4 |       1 |           5 |
|  5 |       1 |           3 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

**User Model**

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'messages', 'user_id', 'receiver_id');
}
```

**Message Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**So what i have tried so far?**

```
    $id = Auth::id();

    $users = User::with(['messages' => function($query) use($id){
        $query->where('user_id', $id)
            ->orWhere('received_id', $id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }])->get();

    dd($users);
```

**What is the expected result?**

Using this query, i am getting all of my 10 users. Although i should only get 4 users(those with id's 2,3,4,5).

If the above query is wrong, or i should follow another method or i should created some sort of relationships Please help.

Hopefully you have understood the question, i am new to Laravel but i am learning.

Comment: On `User` model, `messages()` belongsToMany with `Message` model, so change `User::class` to `Message::class` on that line

Comment: @sta, No it is throwing `Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias`

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is three relations(one to many) in the User model. One for sent messages, one for received messages and one for both, like this:

```
public function messagesSent()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'user_id');
}

public function messagesReceived()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'receiver_id');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->messagesSent()->union($this->messagesReceived()->toBase());
}
```

Then you should be able to get user messages like this: `User::with('messages')->get();`

Comment: I have tried it but it is still returning all(10) users

Comment: My solution is to get the messages of the user and you can use it like this: `$messages = Auth:user()->messages()`. Are you trying to retrieve messages or the users of a message? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the users of the messages that have sent the message to the `user 1` or to whom the `user 1` have sent the message.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a join statement or "whereHas" to select users who have any messages.

```
$id = Auth::id();

$users = User::whereHas('messages', function ($query) use($id){
    $query->where('user_id', $id)
        ->orWhere('received_id', $id);
})
->get();
```

To have access to "messages" you should add "with" statement too.

Comment: `To have access to "messages" you should add "with" statement too` Regarding this can you please provide me how to

Comment: Your solution is working with `public function messages(){ return $this->hasMany(Message::class); }` But can you please check my own answer above? Which is more efficient this one or mine?

Comment: Your solution is better cause it's more clear and reusable, it's good that you make these relations

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer. My solution is clear but i am not able to achieve `$users->messages` with that, but with yours it is working.

Comment: i have tested the code a lot and at the end of the day(when i thought everything is working) then it comes that i am only getting users `who sent me the message` (e.g. from the above table i am only getting users from `user_id` side i.e 3, 4) while those users to whom i sent the messages ARE NOT COMING(e.g. from the above table on the `receiver_id` side 2 and 5 while 3 is returning because 3 is already on the `user_id` side and it already sent me the message)

Comment: Thanks man i have managed to solve it and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own solution(i.e working) to this question.

**User Model**

```
public function sent()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'user_id');
}

public function received()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'receiver_id');
}
```

**Query**

```
$users = User::whereHas('sent', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('receiver_id', $id);
})->orWhereHas('received', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $id);
})->get();

dd($users);
```